# Swift how to convert string to NSDate

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I've got a `date` stored in my database and I want to retrieve it and display it nicely in my tableview cells.

The format it comes in from the database and stored in option1 is `BO05151530`

Where the first two letters have meaning in the program but are not needed for the date so I take those off using the `substringFromIndex` function.

So what is left is `05151530`  where it represents `MMddhmm`

I would like to display it nicely like `MM-dd @ h:mm a`

For example `12-05 @ 3:45 am`

Here is what I tried but unfortunately `ns_date1` comes up as nil each time.

What would you suggest I do?

```
let date1 = option1.substringFromIndex(option1.startIndex.advancedBy(2))

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMddhhmm"

let ns_date1 = dateFormatter.dateFromString(date1)
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. you don't need to separate BO `NSDateFormatter` can handle extra string

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "'BO'MMddHHmm"

let ns_date1 = dateFormatter.dateFromString("BO05151530")

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "'BO' MM-dd @ hh':'mm a"

let string = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(ns_date1!)
```

Comment: The year is something I do not need to show up. How could I make that invisible?

Comment: if you check o/p will be like : "BO 05-15 @ 03:30 PM"

Comment: Only issue I'm having is some of my dates are like 0515930  so only one h and not hh.  Which is causing this to crash when trying to unwrap nil value.

Comment: at that time you need to change your dateformatter to "'BO'MMddHmm"

Answer (score 1):

try

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMddHHmm"
```

> HH is 24 hour format and hh is 12 hour format. you need the 24 one

Comment: The NSDate form now shows up as YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +0000

How could I get it to just be the format I specified?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this app, this will help you know the right format and give you code

https://itunes.apple.com/ae/app/date-format-creator/id965645209?mt=12

[image]

> NOTE: you need to add year to get a correct NSDate

Answer (score 0):

I have this function :

```
class func getTheDateString(stringForInputDate: String, fromFormat inputFormat: String, toFormat outputFormat: String) -> String {
let formatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = inputFormat
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
let dateForInput: NSDate = formatter.dateFromString(stringForInputDate)!
formatter.dateFormat = outputFormat
return formatter.stringFromDate(dateForInput)
```

}

and used it as:

```
let stringDate : String = "0515930" // "05151530"

    if stringDate.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) < 8 {

        print([ViewControllerForScreen1 .getTheDateString(stringDate, fromFormat: "MMddHmm", toFormat: "MM-dd @ h:mm a")]);

    }else {

        print([ViewControllerForScreen1 .getTheDateString(stringDate, fromFormat: "MMddHHmm", toFormat: "MM-dd @ h:mm a")]);

    }
```

OUTPUT:

1. ["05-15 @ 9:30 AM"]
2. ["05-15 @ 3:30 PM"]

Comment: some of my stringForInputDates have the Hour represented with two digits and others just one digit for the hour which is causing this to crash when unwrapping optional nil value.  Any solution for handling that?

Comment: then, you can do this by checking the length of string and as per that pass the input format..